# GUI.BeginScrollView in Unity

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, scrollview

I don't understand how to use a scroll view in Unity. Here is the script I'm using to create my scrollview:

```
#pragma strict

//not implemented yet
var selectObjectIcon : Texture2D;
var addEntityIcon : Texture2D;
var selectNextEntityIcon : Texture2D;
var createPathIcon : Texture2D;
var assignPathIcon : Texture2D;
var changeSpeedIcon : Texture2D;
var deleteObjectIcon : Texture2D;
var zoomIcon : Texture2D;

//not supposed to be implemented
var dragEntityIcon : Texture2D;
var assignPointIcon : Texture2D;
var haltIcon : Texture2D;
var warpIcon : Texture2D;
var glowStickIcon : Texture2D;
var selectWeaponIcon : Texture2D;
var reviveIcon : Texture2D;
var lineOfSightIcon : Texture2D;

var buttonDimensions : float;
var buttonStyle : GUIStyle;

private var scrollPosition : Vector2 = Vector2.zero;

function OnGUI () {
    //scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(Rect(Screen.width-buttonDimensions, 0, buttonDimensions, Screen.height), scrollPosition, Rect(0, 0, buttonDimensions, buttonDimensions));
    scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(Rect(Screen.width-buttonDimensions, 0, buttonDimensions, Screen.height), scrollPosition, Rect(0, 0, buttonDimensions, Screen.height));
    GUILayout.BeginVertical();

    if(GUILayout.Button(selectObjectIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(addEntityIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(selectNextEntityIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(createPathIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(assignPathIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(changeSpeedIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(deleteObjectIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(zoomIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }

    if(GUILayout.Button(dragEntityIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(assignPointIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(haltIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(warpIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(glowStickIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(selectWeaponIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(reviveIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(lineOfSightIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }

    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUI.EndScrollView();
}
```

But this isn't working as intended. The buttons are too far to the right and are being cut off, and I can't scroll them up. I also don't understand what the third argument to BeginScrollView is supposed to bea bout. The docs just say "The rectangle used inside the scrollview.". Am I supposed to be calculating the value for the scroll view window and the window for the contents? I'm coming from Android GUI development and that seems like a lot more work than is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so by trial and error I was able to put the script together to display everything as intended. What bothers me is I needed to estimate the size of the scrollbar and calculate the pixel values for the buttons to create the scrollview. I imagine that for more complex UI's calculating these values explicitly will be very headache inducing. Is there a better way to do this, similar to the relative ease of creating a ListView in Android?

```
#pragma strict

//not implemented yet
var selectObjectIcon : Texture2D;
var addEntityIcon : Texture2D;
var selectNextEntityIcon : Texture2D;
var createPathIcon : Texture2D;
var assignPathIcon : Texture2D;
var changeSpeedIcon : Texture2D;
var deleteObjectIcon : Texture2D;
var zoomIcon : Texture2D;

//not supposed to be implemented
var dragEntityIcon : Texture2D;
var assignPointIcon : Texture2D;
var haltIcon : Texture2D;
var warpIcon : Texture2D;
var glowStickIcon : Texture2D;
var selectWeaponIcon : Texture2D;
var reviveIcon : Texture2D;
var lineOfSightIcon : Texture2D;

var buttonDimensions : float;
var buttonStyle : GUIStyle;

private var scrollPosition : Vector2 = Vector2.zero;
private var scrollBarWidth : float = 17.5;

function OnGUI () {
    scrollPosition = GUI.BeginScrollView(Rect(Screen.width-buttonDimensions-scrollBarWidth-buttonStyle.padding.right, 0, buttonDimensions+scrollBarWidth+buttonStyle.padding.right, Screen.height), scrollPosition, Rect(0, 0, buttonDimensions, (buttonDimensions+buttonStyle.padding.bottom+buttonStyle.padding.top)*16));
    GUILayout.BeginVertical();

    if(GUILayout.Button(selectObjectIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(addEntityIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(selectNextEntityIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(createPathIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(assignPathIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(changeSpeedIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(deleteObjectIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(zoomIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }

    if(GUILayout.Button(dragEntityIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(assignPointIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(haltIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(warpIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(glowStickIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(selectWeaponIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(reviveIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }
    if(GUILayout.Button(lineOfSightIcon, buttonStyle)){
        Debug.Log("select object pressed");
    }

    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUI.EndScrollView();
}
```